# Xamarin DisplayAlert when entry max length reached

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, async-await, binding

I have an entry which is set to max length of 3. When the user tries to input 4 characters I want to display a simple DisplayAlert message as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups). I am trying to implement it with MVVM but having hard time with the binding of the await needed for the alert. I know that the max length will always be 3 if that helps.

Xaml:

```
<Entry Text = "{Binding BoundText}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
string _boundText;
public string BoundText
{
   get => _boundText;
   set
   {
       if(value.Length > 3)
       {
          await DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
       }
       else
       {
          ...
       }
   }
}
```

The error I am getting is that the await operator needs to be in an async method, but when I add it I get an error that the modifier async is not valid for the constructor. Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't place  an async method into `Setter` method .

And it is not recommended to place `DisplayAlert` into viewmodel , cause the method belongs to page , it breaks mvvm pattern .

Here are **two workarounds** .

1. Send `MessagingCenter` in `Setter` method , and do something in page .

   ```
        //viewmodel
        set
            {
                if (value.Length > 3)
                {
                    MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "Hi");
                }
            ...


        //page
        public Page1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = model;

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "Hi", async (obj) =>
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
            });
        }
   ```
2. Handle it in `TextChanged` of Entry .

   ```
     <Entry Text = "{Binding BoundText}" TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged"/>


       private async void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           if(e.NewTextValue.Length > 3)
           {
               await DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: Yes, this is why it only could be a workaround not solution, and the second way is recommended.

Comment: Thank you, I am using the TextChanged as advised. Will solve the logic of how to set the MaxLength of the entry to 3 and still display the message :)